# Настройка meta тэгов facebook для страниц с динамическим контентом

Tags: javascript, facebook, meta, spa

Есть сайт интернет-журнала. Есть один шаблон в который я загружаю контент каждой отдельной статьи. В каждой статье соответственно есть свои собственные кнопки fb "поделиться".
**И вот тут у меня возникает сложность:**
Я хочу, что бы в посте на fb появлялась своя заглавная картинка из каждой статьи. Для этого надо прописывать `<meta class="img-meta" property="og:image" content="прямая ссылка на нужную картинку" />`. Параметр `content` я конечно прописываю скриптом исходя из загруженного контента, но краулер fb, выполняя скрапинг страницы, js вообще не запускает, читает только HTML в котором я могу прописать ссылку только на какую-то одну картинку.
Как с этим быть?

Comment: Да вообще-то никак. Вы сами ответили: "js вообще не запускает". Т.е. Вам надо найти возможность прописывать ссылку на картинку в процессе генерации страницы. Чтобы загруженный HTML уже имел окончательный вариант <meta>

Answer (score 1):

Ну собственно, я решил записывать эти метатэги с помощью php.
Из адресной строки получать путь к папке со статьёй и от туда из дополнительного jsonа получать всю нужную информацию.